# set method in react hooks does not set the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
let [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(100);

function ChangeHandler(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  setAmount(value);
  props.update(amount);
}
```

`props.update` is a function that I passed from a higher component to update another Hook.

Comment: Can you add more details?

Comment: The update is asynchronous, more in the linked question's answers and [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value). `setAmount` **will** definitely update your state item. It won't update the in-scope variable that functions may close over; you need to make sure your functions don't have state closures. (Note: use `const` when declaring your state members: `const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(100);`. It helps you remember that *that* variable will never change, the change is in the one you get **next time** you call `useState`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the state after setting it in next line.

do it like that

```
let [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(100);

function ChangeHandler(event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  setAmount(value);
  props.update(value);
}
```

Comment: it does not work i tried. but thanks

Comment: not possible, you are doing something wrong

Comment: the update function works but the setAmount does not

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote and check this answer as the best answer for you by clicking on the right arrow, thanks!